# User is always null - listener called BEFORE the security firewall

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to customize my errors pages : 404, 403 & 500 Code Error .

I want to show Menu in the page error according to connected user, But i cant get current user because the listener of exeption if called BEFORE the security firewall.

There is any solution to resolve this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting to you to read this page [Symfony cookbook chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#avoiding-exceptions-when-using-security-functions-in-error-templates)

or [this chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller) if you need some variables

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please whenever you add a reference to an external site, summarize the content, because the link may become invalid in the future and then your answer will be lost!

Comment: Thank you, I got it and i'll edit my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, but when i ask a question in stack, it means that i was reading all documentation.

Comment: Can we have the code of your error pages' templates ?